# Cannot parse '12/16/2022, 1:33 pm' using 'M/d/yyyy, h:mm a' format pattern into a LocalDateTime object

Tags: java, time, java-time, datetime-parsing, localdatetime

The value `12/16/2022, 1:33 pm` looks to match to expected format pattern `M/d/yyyy, h:mm a`, what is incorrect `at index 17`?

Java unit test:

```
@Test
public void testLocalDateTime_shortDateTimePattern() {
    String pattern = "M/d/yyyy, h:mm a";
    System.out.println(pattern);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

    String dateString = "12/16/2022, 1:33 pm";
    System.out.println(dateString);

    LocalDateTime result = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Console output:

```
M/d/yyyy, h:mm a
12/16/2022, 1:33 pm

Text '12/16/2022, 1:33 pm' could not be parsed at index 17
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '12/16/2022, 1:33 pm' could not be parsed at index 17
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
```

Comment: are you sure `pm` is the correct spelling for your default `Locale`? (I had no problem with posted code - using `Locale.UK`)

Comment: Is it common to use lower-case AM/PM in UK? That's interesting, I have to check it out soon…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**
Index 17 is *AM/PM of day*
**Problems:**

- it's lower case in the `String`
- its format and language depend on the `Locale` of the JVM if you don't apply one explicitly

If you can change the input `String`, you should make the `pm` (or `am`) upper case, otherwise use a `DateTimeFormatter` that parses case insensitive(ly). You can use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` for that.

In any case add a `Locale` since `AM/PM` is not everywhere exactly one of those two abbreviations (on my German JVM it would be `nachm.`, abbreviating `nachmittags`, which means something like `at noon`).

Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define the pattern (your original one should do)
    String pattern = "M/d/yyyy, h:mm a";
    // build a formatter that handles the lower-case AM/PM of day
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                            .appendPattern(pattern)
                                            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    // example input / datetime
    String dateString = "12/16/2022, 1:33 pm";
    // parse with the formatter
    LocalDateTime resultB = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
    // print the result
    System.out.println(resultB);
}
```

Output:

```
2022-12-16T13:33
```

**Small hint** (because I just made that mistake myself):
the call to `.parseCaseInsensitive()` must come before appending the (relevant part of) the pattern. Otherwise the formatter would only know to parse case insensitively afterwards, which then fails with the same `DateTimeParseException`.

---

**Update:**
Obviously, UK's standard is lower case, so you can use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.UK)`, too. There may be more such `Locale`s, but a fix one is less flexible than a formatter that parses case insensitively (IMHO).